Multiple Criteria in GooGle Sheets
I am trying to get both "Win" and "MTT Cash" results
=COUNTIFS(ResultsLog!C:C,A11,ResultsLog!F:F,"Win" & "MTT Cash")

It works when I just have "Win" but if I add & "MTT Cash"
then it returns 0
All help appreciated

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.


You may try:
=countifs(ResultsLog!C:C,A11,index(xmatch(ResultsLog!F:F,{"Win","MTT Cash"})^0),1)


You may also try QUERY() with matches operator.
=QUERY(ResultsLog!C:F,"select count(C) where C='" & A11 & "' and F matches 'Win|MTT Cash' label count(C) ''")


